# When debugging in Visual Studio Comunity the code does not break on the "Multiple controls with the same ID error"?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

An update panel in the masterpage does not allow the debugger to work in Visual Studio Community 2015. Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: If you have debugging working at all then I'd guess your problem is finding where your error is occurring and putting a break point before that

Comment: Ok thanks @mickadoo - Debugging is working - but if I have multiple controls with the same ID in the page it won’t break and find that error in runtime. 
It just stalls in the browser, this only happens in Visual Studio Community - Visual Studio 2013 breaks on the error and returns to the code behind as normal. 
I am trying to get to the bottom of what settings may have changed as it makes debugging the front end code very difficult. Thanks again.
.